# How to get only one field by comparing other field of same model in view file of Django

Tags: python, django

I want to run this query:

```
"SELECT pname FROM PaientSignup WHERE email=p_email"
```

I used filter method that gives me all other data that match with email given.

```
p= PatientSignup.objects.filter(email=p_email)
```

From that output I could not able to fetch on name of patient.

- models.py

  ```
  class PatientSignup(models.Model):
      pid = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Patient Id', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
      pname = models.CharField(verbose_name='Enter Name', max_length=50, default=NameError)
      email = models.CharField(verbose_name='Enter Email', max_length=100,unique=True)
      age = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Enter age',default=5, null=True)
      password = models.CharField(verbose_name='Enter Password',max_length=12)
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  def pFeedback(request):
      #feedback = textarea input
      p_email = request.session['pusername']
      #here, I want only patient name->pname to store in database
      saveFeedback = patientFeedback()
      saveFeedback.feedback = feedback
      saveFeedback.patientName = patient
      saveFeedback.save()
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `PatientSignup.objects.filter(email=p_email).values_list('pname', flat=True)`. It will returns list of names matching with email.

Comment: It returns queryset. SO to take name does I have to run for loop on queryset object???

Comment: values_list() returns a list. So to take names just iterate over the list.